# In R using Shiny, is there a way to use the previous state of checkboxGroupInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using "appendTab" to dynamically grow my tabsetPanel, when I do the code bellow I get the full list of checked items in my tabset.  The problem that I don't know how to address, is when you check or unchecked an item from the input, it appends the entire list again.

## in ui.R

```
  checkboxGroupInput("states", 
                     label = h5("Selected States"), 
                     choices = state.name,
                     selected = c("Minnesota", "Wisconsin","North Dakota", "Ohio", "South Dakota", "Iowa"),
                     inline = TRUE),
```

## in server.R

```
 observe({
   for (i in input$states){
    local({
    testi <- i
    appendTab("myTabs",
              tabPanel(i, tags$p(
                fluidRow(
                  column(6,
                         renderUI({
                           inclRmd("./ColumnLeft.Rmd")
                           })
                         ),
                  column(6,
                         renderUI({
                           inclRmd("./ColumnRight.Rmd")
                           })
                         )
                  )
                )), 
              select=TRUE)
    })
  }

 })
```

Is there a way to preserve the previous state of the input to use removeTab before my use of appendTab?  Is there a better approach to using checkboxGroupInput to create tabs?

Comment: A better approach here is to render the entire UI (the tabsetPanel) with renderUI, based on the selected options in your checkboxgroupinput. There you can use `do.call` to make the tabitems programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full working example. Note the definition of a `state_ui_fun`, a function to define the content of the tabs. Here you could also send arguments, like the state name and whatever.

```
state_ui_fun <- function(state){

  fluidRow(
    column(6, tags$p("Left content")),
    column(6, tags$p("Right content"))
  )

}


ui <- fluidPage(


  checkboxGroupInput("states", 
                     label = h5("Selected States"), 
                     choices = state.name,
                     selected = c("Minnesota", "Wisconsin","North Dakota", "Ohio", "South Dakota", "Iowa"),
                     inline = TRUE),

  tags$hr(),

  uiOutput("ui_statepanel")

)


server <- function(input, output, session){



  output$ui_statepanel <- renderUI({

    state_choice <- input$states

    do.call(tabsetPanel,
            lapply(state_choice,  function(state){

              tabPanel(title = state, state_ui_fun())

            })
    )


  })



}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as I desired.  I do admit that I have no idea why it works, can you explain a bit what the do.call and lapply functions are doing?

Comment: `lapply` makes a list, where each element is a tabPanel (one for each selected state). Then `do.call` takes that list and uses it as arguments to `tabsetPanel` (this is necessary because tabsetPanel cannot take a list as an input directly).

Comment: Thank you, I have used lapply before so that's doing what I thought, the do.call was the bigger mystery, but I think I get it.  The explanation is Greatly Appreciated.